# Jquery .load() sends POST parameters only once per page load

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have this script:

```
  $('#openBtn').click(function(){

       $(".modal-body").load("/show.php?fFuehIFj1L0vS6Hp", {oi: $("#oi").val(), txtid:    $("#txtid").val()}, function(result){
        $('#myModal').modal({show:true});
     });

});
```

And this html:

```
 <a href="#" class="btn" id="openBtn">Open modal</a>

 <div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
        <h3>Modal header</h3>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
    <p>My modal content here…</p>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
</div>
```

I want to send POST variables and retrieve remote page every click, but now it sends POST variables on only first click, after that i must refresh my page .

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you have a tabindex on that div? I've never seen that before.

Comment: `load()` uses `GET`, so it doesn't really send `POST` parameters at all ?

Comment: @adaneo, The POST method is used if data is provided as an object

Answer (score 0):

did you mean hashchange on javascript?
just like this

site.com/blah#content=1

```
function hash()
{
var hash = window.location.href;
hash = split("#", hash);
hash = hash[1]; // this is hash param
return hash;
}

$(window).on('hashchange', function() {
$("#page").load("index.php?"+hash());
});

$(window).ready(function() {
$("#page").load("index.php?"+hash());
});
```